# Modifying size of input images for Chainer DCGAN model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, chainer, dcgan

I'm using the Chainer DCGAN example file found at https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/examples/dcgan/train_dcgan.py . It works fine for 32x32 images, but for other resolutions, the README.md instructs to modify the network architecture in net.py.

As I understand it from reading the documentation, the size of the training images is sent as a parameter to the constructor to the Generator class, as bottom_width, and ch. Here is the code for a 32x32.

```
class Generator(chainer.Chain):

    def __init__(self, n_hidden, bottom_width=4, ch=512, wscale=0.02):
```

I'm confused as to how this translates to 32x32, and how to modify this to other resolutions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate it by understanding the behavior of `Deconvolution2D`.
In [`net.py`](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/examples/dcgan/net.py#L30-L33), 3 Deconvolution2D layer (`self.dc1`, `self.dc2`, `self.dc3`) is defined with `stride=2` (4-th argument of `L.Deconvolution2D`), which doubles the input height/width.

As a result, output size will be `bottom_size * 2^3`, which results to 32 when `bottom_size=4`.

So for example, if you want to get 64x64 images you can set `bottom_size=8` for both generator & discriminator (but you need 64x64 images as real data, instead of cifar-100 which is 32x32 images).

Please refer official document for the details of input-output size relationship.

- [chainer.functions.deconvolution_2d](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.functions.deconvolution_2d.html#chainer-functions-deconvolution-2d)

Comment: I thought I accepted this answer back when I first posted it. Sorry for the delay. It works!